# Extracting all links in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, web-crawler, html-parsing

I want to extract the list of all government websites of India for my survey.

The list is found here :
http://goidirectory.nic.in/index.php

The problem here is that the list is not in the form of links. Whenever I need to open a website it opens a new tab and from there it redirects to the website requested.

So, google klipper and other tools which extracts links from website isn't working.

I don't know anything about javascript.

One thing I noticed is that when I put a mouse pointer to the link it shows the name of the website link as shown below:

[image: Mouse pointer]

like for eg http://presidentofindia.gov.in comes in the highlight.

I need list of such websites links

Thanks

Comment: Please I request all the people of stackoverflow community, give me few tips on how to improve this question. I am trying my best to remove the posed ban on question limit on my account. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/9b0wL9tn/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
});
```

NOTE: Open website in chrome >> right click >> inspect >> go to console tab and paste the following and press enter

Run this code first on console:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type.
jQuery.noConflict();
```

**then run this**

```
$('a').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

this will list all the links on the page just copy it from console

**UPDATE**

Have updated the script after following the prev steps... run the following script in console:

```
var arr=new Array();
jQuery('a').each(function(i){


arr[i]=jQuery(this).attr('title')+"";


});

jQuery.each(arr,function(i){
if(arr[i].indexOf('http')>-1)
console.log(arr[i].substr(0, arr[i].indexOf('-')));
});
```

here is the screenshot : http://www.imageno.com/lj7tuyr9pt2opic.html

Comment: When I pasted the latter code into console and pressed enter, I got the following error:
"VM214:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).each is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ VM214:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM90:878InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM90:811InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM90:667"

Comment: maybe that is coz the site doest use jQuery

Comment: or add this extension to your chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquerify/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc?hl=en

Comment: These are not the links which I require. Please open the site once, these links are embedded in the javascript query which opens the site. It should contain links as mentioned in the question.

Comment: give me exact webpage url